# Expected unqualified-id before '*' token: Pointer to Member Functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers, compiler-errors

I'm trying to run this code but cannot understand what is causing the error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
    public:
        void show ( float ) { cout << "Hello"; }
};

int main ( )
{

    void (Shape::*FPtr2) (float) = &Shape :: show;
    (Shape::*FPtr2)(1.1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To call `show` you need a `Shape` *object*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling a non-static member function requires an object.  Calling a non-static member function via pointer-to-member function also requires an object.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
    public:
        void show ( float ) { cout << "Hello"; }
};

int main ( )
{
    void (Shape::*FPtr2) (float) = &Shape :: show;
    Shape myShape;  // here is my object
    (myShape.*FPtr2)(1.1);  // here is the call to the object's show function via pointer
    return 0;
}
```